# Retrieving an image from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-imageview

With the code I am using, the compiler doesn't make it past the first if statement and returns the message "The object was not found ... ". I am trying to download an image from parse.com and place it in an imageView.  Attached is my code, the schema for parse class and my XML layout.

```
final ParseImageView mImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers");
    query.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
    query.getInBackground("imageFiles", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Log.d("test", "The object was not found...");

            } else {
                Log.d("test", "Retrieved the object.");
                final ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("imageFiles");
                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
                            // use data for something
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
                            mImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        } else {
                            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: parse.com]

[image: content_appetizer_recipe.xml]

[image: design of layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sending class:

```
ParseObject po = mAppetizers.get(position); // get position
String ID = po.getObjectId().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(Appetizer.this, AppetizerRecipe.class);

intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the receiver's class:

```
final ParseImageView mImage = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
String ID = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> getimage = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers");
    getimage.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
    getimage.whereEqualTo("ID", ID);
        Log.d("AppetizerRecipe2", "object: " + ID);
    getimage.getInBackground(ID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.v("what is e?", "e = " + e);
                // success
                final ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)object.get("imageFiles");
                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
                            // use data for something
                            Log.d("test", "Get your image..." + fileObject.getUrl());
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(fileObject.getUrl()).placeholder
                            (R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(mImage);

                        } else {
                            Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // fail
                Log.d("test", "Error Message..." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try on this way.
i have change few changes in your existing code like...

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Appetizers");
    query.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (e == null) {
                // success
                for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("imageFiles");

                    Log.d("test", "get your image ... " + fileObject.getUrl());
                }
            } else {
                // fail
                Log.d("test", "error Message... " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```